# Is it safe to reuse an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

The Android docs define an Intent as "a bundle of information containing an abstract description of an operation to perform". This suggests that you should be able to reuse a single Intent object multiple times if needed, but I haven't seen any examples showing this is the case/ is safe to do. Is there any reason to NOT do the following:

```
private final Intent enableBluetoothIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  enabledBluetoothIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
  ...
}
```

and then call `startActivityForResult(enableDiscoverableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT_DISCOVERY)` in multiple places in the code? What happens if the same intent is started twice?

Comment: What's an example of when you would reuse an `Intent`? I sometimes create an `Intent` object then use it in different places in the `Activity` depending on which conditions are met and when. Don't know if that helps at all...

Comment: My example is requesting bluetooth access, which launches a popup asking the user to confirm or deny bluetooth. This can happen in a few different places. If we use the intent and bluetooth gets turned on successfully, but then later bluetooth is turned off elsewhere, we want to request it again. Using the same object seems cleanest since we just want to send the same request.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me and I don't see any issues. However, in some situations you may want to use `Intent flags` to do things such as clear any similar tasks that have been started from this `Intent` from the stack

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is completely safe when you want to use it to do the exact same thing, since an `Intent` is no more than a bunch of data and instructions. If you want to use the same `Intent` object for different purposes (for example you have a bunch of tabs and try to set the tabs reusing the same intent but changing the activity they'll launch) you have to be more careful, and I'd recommend re-creating a new `Intent` object for each.