# Is it safe to send sensitive data via Intent or Fragment.setArguments()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, password-protection

When you pass data to Activity by using `Intent.putExtra()` (or `setArguments()` is case of Fragment) the data is keep in some place by Android as it can be restore after Activity/Fragment is killed.

I would like to know whether it safe to pass sensitive information such as password to another Activity/Fragment. In other words, can anyone search the data that stored by Android.

To make thing more clear, **I do not store users' password**. I just want to pass the password to another Activity/Fragment to handle registration process.

Comment: Please don't worry!!! it is 100% safe.

Comment: Even on rooted device?

Comment: Brother rooted device have no guarantee what is does with are data.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is 100 % safe. because intent data not physically store any ware in App or device it is logically store by Android system so just create your own key to store data and it is safe.

more detail check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

and also refer this link: [Is it safe to reuse an intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285137/is-it-safe-to-reuse-an-intent)

Comment: Where in the doc that mention you answer.

Comment: there are no any documentation but when you use intent in your app then its scope will be run your app. after close your app and if you create intent then it is recreated. so dont wory about confidentiality

Comment: http://blog.palominolabs.com/2013/05/13/android-security/ see this link it will more clear info about intent safety.

Comment: As the question itself makes obvious, this answer is wrong.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @ChrisStratton, if you use intent to pass data than you share it with system, you are NOT keeping it inside your process only.